# Efficient way to use PyInstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm producing an .exe file via PyInstaller and I wonder whether there is a specific option or similar to do so while iterating through some changes. For example, I add a simple print statement in the entire code, do I always have to go through the whole building stage of the .exe file?
I'm asking because it takes a while just to try something out. In my case I think it takes between 5-10 min to create the .exe. In general it's ok but when you do that a dozens or more times a day it adds up.

Comment: Once the executable is compiled and created, there is no way to edit it to make small adjustments. You can reduce compilation time using the generated `.spec` , and make sure you are not removing the previous compilations `build`  directory.

Comment: Thank you, could you please elaborate more on how to do so? How exactly do I use the .spec file?

Comment: [using spec files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)